# Pyspark kernel in jupyterhub, access to master remotely

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

i have two kernels for Spark, one to run locally and one to run towards a cluster. Is there a way to set an environment variable to my spark master so that users dont have to define master in SparkContext in the kernel which is to speak with the spark cluster? I tried "export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='spark:/my-server.domain.com:7077' ", however that did not work.

Code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import random

def inside(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return x*x + y*y < 1


sc = SparkContext(master="spark:/my-server.domain.com:7077", appName="test")

num_samples = 2

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()

pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)

sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Master URL in spark-defaults.conf file on your local spark installation. Apart from that, passing the master URL in SparkContext like you did, you can pass the master url on the command-line with `--master` while launching your Pyspark Jupyter notebook

Comment: The master i want to connect to runs on remote server, and i want to forward jobs to that master from my PySpark kernel, and not forward if PySpark_local kernel is used. Maybe passing master in Context is the way to go